# How to clean up FBX. files imported from VectorWorks CAD software

Tags: rendering, uv, vertices, geometry, .fbx

The .fbx files I import into Blender from my CAD program seem overly complex for simple shapes. Is there a way to simplify the geometry/remove vertices so I have easier planes to work with for unwrapping, image textures etc.? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
-thanks[image],

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75263/any-tips-for-simplifying-cad-models https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141181/importing-models-from-autocad-to-blender/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48542/best-way-to-bevel-corners-for-rendering-imported-cad-models/